# Нормали в Блендер 2.83

Tags: blender

Скачала Блендер 2.83. Стала его изучать. И оказалось, что нормали вытянуты в одну сторону. Это происходит даже если создаешь новый файл. Пробовала все, чтобы их вывернуть на место. Что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В стандартном интерфейсе Blender можно отображать три типа нормалей: нормали к вершинам, нормали к вершинам на грань и нормали к граням. Обычно розовым цветом отображаются нормали к вершинам на грань, но на представленной картинке это не соответствует, поскольку нормали выходят не из вершин. Поэтому по представленной картинке сложно судить о причинах происходящего, нужен файл с этим кубом.

Традиционно большинство проблем с нормалями в штатном режиме решается через [пересчет нормалей](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html#recalculate).